# Racket function that returns all numbers whose sum is <= given number?

Tags: racket

I'm taking an intro to computer science course and one question needs me to write a function that takes a list of numbers and a number and returns the numbers in the list whose sum is less than the given number. I've written the function signature, definition, and check-expects, but I'm stuck. The function needs to assume intermediate student with lambda. I don't want any direct answers here; just help so that I can reach the answer myself.

I know it needs to use recursion. Perhaps a helper function would be needed.

```
;; sum-up-to: lon, number -> lon
;; consumes a list of numbers and a number and
;; returns the numbers in the list whose sum is
;; less than or equal to the given number

(define the-numbers (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(check-expect (sum-up-to the-numbers 7) (list 1 2 3))
(check-expect (sum-up-to the-numbers 18) (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(check-expect (sum-up-to the-numbers 45) the-numbers)
```

Comment: Can we assume that the input list is sorted in ascending order? If not, can we use an existing sorting procedure?

Comment: Yes, ascending order. It only returns the first numbers in the list that sum is less than or equal to the given number.

Comment: Ok, then my answer is right :) . Just forget about sorting the input list, because we can assume that the list is already sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be simplified if we sort the list first and if we define a helper function that keeps track of the accumulated sum. Here's a skeleton, fill-in the blanks with the missing expressions and you'll have the solution:

```
(define (sum-up-to lst n)
  (helper <???> n 0)) ; sort the input list, pass it to the helper

(define (helper lst n sum)
  (cond (<???> '())       ; if the list is empty, end the recursion
        ((> <???> n) '()) ; also end recursion if sum + current element > n
        (else
         (cons <???>         ; otherwise cons current element
               (helper <???> ; advance recursion over list
                       n
                       (+ <???> <???>)))))) ; update sum
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Following recursive method keeps adding numbers from the list sequentially to an initially empty outlist, till the sum is reached:

```
(define the-numbers (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))

(define (f lst sum)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (ol '()))
    (if (or (..ENTER CONDITION FOR EMPTY LIST..)
            (..ENTER CONDITION WHEN SUM IS REACHED..)
        (..ENTER HOW TO PUT THE NEW LIST OUT..)
        (loop (..ENTER ARGUMENTS TO BE SENT TO NEXT LOOP..)
        ))))

(f the-numbers 7)
(f the-numbers 18)
(f the-numbers 45)
```

Output:

```
'(1 2 3)
'(1 2 3 4 5)
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: I have modified my answer above.